# Attempting Reverse Proxy with Apache httpd. Can't get URL Rewriting to work

Tags: url-rewriting, apache2, httpd.conf

I have [Sventon](http://sventon.org) running on port 8090 of my server under Apache Tomcat. I also have Apache httpd running on this server, and I'd like to have users type in:

```
http://myserver.com/repos
```

To get to Sventon instead of:

```
http://myserver.com:8090/svn
```

I've tried to setup a ReverseProxy and mostly successful. Typing in:

```
http://myserver.com/repos
```

Gets you to Sventon, but the URL in the browser changes to:

```
http://myserver:8090/svn
```

I'd like to hide the change in the URL, and I have the following configuration:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /repos http://myserver.company.com:8090/svn
#ProxyPassReverse /repos http://myserver.company.com:8090/svn

<Location /repos>
        ProxyPassReverse /
        SetOutputFilter proxy-html
#       ProxyHTMLInterp  On
        ProxyHTMLURLMap  /      /repos
        RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
</Location>
```

This might seem minor, but we plan to do this with all of our other systems. We're running Jira, Confluence, Jenkins, etc. Some on this system, and some on other systems. I'd like to get it setup, so that I have simple set of URLs:

```
http://myserver.company.com/issues
http://myserver.company.com/wiki
http://myserver.company.com/builds
http://myserver.company.com/repos
```

Instead of something like this:

```
http://anotherserver.company.com:8090/jira
http://asecondserver.company.com:8999/confluence
http://asecondserver.company.com:8080/
http://myserver.company.com/8090/svn
```

As I said, the ReverseProxy seems to be working. It does go to the other URL, but it changes the URL in the browser (which we want to hide).

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sventon-support/TmfiJPvF95s/discussion

http://wiki.sventon.org/index.php?n=Main.OptionalVariables